# How to debug console warnings in React using "strict" mode?

Tags: reactjs, debugging, webpack, console, strict

I've been annoyed with Strict mode for a while, particularly because it's very difficult to trace down where in a React application a certain warning/error is coming from.  If it's a breaking error, React will usually say exactly where it's happening with a code snippet.  Not for strict mode though.

I believe this may also be because Webpack is building the application so everything is minified.  If I click on the line number it sends me to the React library function call (minified), and the stack trace is equally unhelpful.

For example, currently in a React app I have the following errors and I'm not sure where to start.

[image]

Comment: Just remove strict mode, or when you build react, set it to use production mode which disables strict mode.

Comment: I like strict mode for many things, it's just these kind of warnings that are hard to debug that really drive me crazy.  I'd rather learn just how to better find and fix these.

Comment: Run react without minimizing it and it'll give you a much better error message so you can know where to fix it. Though it's likely in one of your dependencies which is sometimes hard to remove/work around.